# Hand-crafted Chef API requests - getting "invalid signature for user"

Tags: c#, chef-infra

For various reasons I need to be able to make Chef API requests in C#. I've followed the guides [here](http://docs.opscode.com/api_chef_server.html) (Header specification) and [here](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/auth.html) (Bash example) but have reached a dead end. Every request I send comes back 401 Unauthorized with the content

```
{"error":["Invalid signature for user or client 'myuser'"]}
```

I have also configured Knife locally to use Fiddler as a HTTP proxy so I can inspect Knife HTTP requests and have copied the visible headers as accurately as possible, but naturally I cannot see the canonical header it generated nor the one the server expects.

However, I have confirmed in this way that the hashes I'm generating for the content (empty) and path are the same as Knife is generating.

Here's my code. Loading the RSA private key from PEM format is using an extension method taken from Christian Etter's blog - run out of links sorry.

```
const string path = "/cookbooks"
const string basePath = "https://chefserver.internal:443";

var timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
var method = "GET";
var clientName = "myuser";

var hashedPath = ToBase64EncodedSha1String(path);
var hashedBody = ToBase64EncodedSha1String(String.Empty);

var canonicalHeader = String.Format("Method:{0}\nHashed Path:{1}\nX-Ops-Content-Hash:{2}\nX-Ops-Timestamp:{3}\nX-Ops-UserId:{4}",
        method, hashedPath, hashedBody, timestamp, clientName);

var privateKey = File.ReadAllText("C:\\chef\\myuser.private.pem");
string signature;
byte[] rawData;

using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
    rsa.LoadPrivateKeyPEM(privateKey);
    using (var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        rawData = rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalHeader), sha1);
        signature = Convert.ToBase64String(rawData);
    }
}

var client = new HttpClient();
var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
message.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
message.RequestUri = new Uri(basePath + path);
message.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
message.Headers.Add("Host", "chefserver.internal:443");
message.Headers.Add("X-Chef-Version", "11.12.4");
message.Headers.Add("X-Ops-Timestamp", timestamp);
message.Headers.Add("X-Ops-Sign", "version=1.0;");
message.Headers.Add("X-Ops-Userid", clientName);
message.Headers.Add("X-Ops-Content-Hash", hashedBody);
message.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Chef Knife/11.4.0 (ruby-1.9.2-p320; ohai-6.16.0; x86_64-darwin11.3.0; +http://opscode.com)");

var currentItem = new StringBuilder();
var i = 1;
foreach (var l in signature)
{
    currentItem.Append(l);
    if (currentItem.Length == 60)
    {
        message.Headers.Add("X-Ops-Authorization-" + i, currentItem.ToString());
        i++;
        currentItem = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
message.Headers.Add("X-Ops-Authorization-" + i, currentItem.ToString());

var response = await client.SendAsync(message);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

And the helper

```
private string ToBase64EncodedSha1String(string input)
{
        return
            Convert.ToBase64String(new    SHA1CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and found that the .NET crypto libraries did not support what was needed to make this work. I ended up using the BouncyCastle crypto libraries to accomplish this.

I made a simple C# class library that wraps this up. Take a look at that here: https://github.com/mattberther/dotnet-chef-api

Comment: Thanks for this. I had tried the BouncyCastle encryption libraries but compared the output to the RSA C# classes and found the outputs to be identical. However, it looks like you're doing something a bit different. I'll try yours when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familiar with C# crypto, but the docs on SHA1CryptoServiceProvider seem to show that is is signing a SHA1 hash. Chef doesn't use signed hashes, you actually need to do an RSA signature on `canonicalHeader` itself.

```
SignData(Byte[], Object): Computes the hash value of the specified byte array using the specified hash algorithm, and signs the resulting hash value.
```

Is there a null or pass-through hash you can use?

Comment: My understanding of RSA signatures esd that the hashing is mandatory. However, looks like this assumption may have been flawed. It won't let me use a pass-through hash, but I did try shelling out to "openssl rsautl" on the command line and it produces a different result - still "Invalid signature for user", though.